# SSL operation failed with code 1 Codeigniter does not send email

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, openssl, xampp

> A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1978

Codeigniter does not send e-mail because of this error.

My e-mail code:

```
$config = Array(
        'protocol'  => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 587,
        'smtp_crypto' => 'tls',
        'smtp_user' => 'asd@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'asd',
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'charset'   => 'utf-8'
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('asd@gmail.com', 'asd');
    $this->email->to($asd);

    $this->email->subject($asd);
    $this->email->message($asd);

    $this->email->send();
```

Comment: Your port is set on TSL.. change it to 465 and remove the smtp_crypto line

Comment: It gave me  fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  error. If I use ssl://smtp.gmail.com then it gave me fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed error

Comment: @IlanHasanov - Gmail only accepts TLS; see [Google Is Now Always Using TLS/SSL for Gmail Connections](http://www.internetsociety.org/deploy360/blog/2014/03/google-now-always-using-tlsssl-for-gmail-connections/). Also see [What is the difference between ports 465 and 587?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15796530/608639)

Comment: Set your CACert file. See, for example, [curl_setopt cacert.pem for paypal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15362350).  Or better, set it to the one CA that's needed (rather than the collection in ***`cacert.pem`***).

Comment: What CA do I need? Could you explain this please?

Comment: I am getting same errors for CI Email library.
I did not changed code. It was working fine for last few month and it started showing these error for last 2 days.
We did not made any changes to server as well.

Comment: I am getting same error any one have solution please post and or paste line please.

Answer (score 2):

**This might help someone in the future.**

Even if every credential is right, some antivirus or firewall installed in the machine might prevent sending email thru SMTP. Temporarily disabling the antivirus or firewall to check is a good idea.

In my case, Avast antivirus caused this issue, and disabling this resolved my problem.

To disable Avast intercepting SMTP, unchecking `Scan outbound emails (SMTP)` checkbox will do the trick.

[image: Disable Avast SMTP interception]